# No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install Tensorflow. I did the installation using the cmd.exe prompt and the installation was a success. But when I try to import TensorFlow appear the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'
```

I follow this steps to install tensorflow:

```
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install tensorflow
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of `tensorflow-serving-api` and update it with

```
$ pip install tensorflow-serving-api==X.Y.0
```

`X` and `Y` should match your TensorFlow version. You can determine your TensorFlow version with

```
$ pip freeze | grep tensorflow
```