# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, modulenotfounderror

My tensorflow version is 'tensorflow==2.4.1'

When I execute 'pip install tensorflow as tf',
an error code appeared,
**"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'"
**
What should I do? TT

I tried to delete tf and reinstall, but i wasn't work.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74632821/17200348) seems related.

Comment: well.... I already tried it but it isn't work.... :(

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment by chance?

Comment: Hi @yoojinyoon, Which python version and system OS are you using? Please refer to this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) official link as per your system OS to install tensorflow in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of TensorFlow serving api :

```
pip install tensorflow-serving-api == 2.14.0
```

Here the latest version is 2.14 .

Hence your TensorFlow version should also be 2.14.

Before you install tf serving, make sure your TF2.x version is 2.14.

On the safer side, do a

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.14
```